# SQLITE / Find the IDs and names of all students who have not taken any course offering before Spring 2010

Tags: sql, sqlite

Question :  Find the IDs and names of all students who have not taken any course offering before Spring 2010.

`[takes]` table

```
ID    course_id    year (only two data : 2009,2010)
101   CS-400       2009
202   CS-347       2010
303   PHY-191      2009
...
...
```

`[student]` table

```
ID    NAME
101   JUN
202   TYO
303   EOA
......
......
```

`[section]` table

```
course_id year
CS-400    2009
CS-347    2010
PHY-191   2009
....
...
```

I want to find that the person who did not take the class in 2009 but only in 2010.

my code

```
select distinct id,name
from student as S
where not exists(select course_id from section where year=2009
                 except
                 select T.course_id from takes as T where S.ID=T.ID);
```

but the result is empty.

Comment: Are you using mysql or sqlite? Only tag the database you're using.

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results *as text*, not images (A `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements would be ideal so people can just copy and paste into a test database).

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Please provide a MRE as described for the tag you used. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sqlite/info

Answer (score 2):

You can join `student` to `takes`, group by student and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
select s.id, s.name 
from student s
inner join takes t on t.id = s.id
group by s.id, s.name 
having min(t.year) = 2010
```

If you are interested only in the years 2009 and 2010 you could also add a `WHERE` clause:

```
select s.id, s.name 
from student s
inner join takes t on t.id = s.id
where t.year in (2009, 2010) 
group by s.id, s.name 
having min(t.year) = 2010
```